# Can't Add Child Block to category.products

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, catalog

I am new to Magento .

I have a problem while trying to add a block to ‘category.products’, but if I try to add a block to ‘content’, it works perfect.  I searched through Stack Exchange, but I couldn’t find any solution for my problem.

In my layout file (located at `app/design/frontend/default/hookahs/layout/webwhales/seoblock.xml`), I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="category.products">
            <block type="webwhales_variousmodule/catalog_categoryseo" name="webwhales_seoblock" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

My layout file is being loaded, because I can remove a sidebar for example.

The config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Root node for Magento configuration files -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <WebWhales_VariousModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </WebWhales_VariousModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <webwhales_variousmodule>
                <class>WebWhales_VariousModule_Block</class>
            </webwhales_variousmodule>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <webwhales_variousmodule>
                <class>WebWhales_VariousModule_Model</class>
            </webwhales_variousmodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <webwhales_variousmodule>
                    <file>webwhales/seoblock.xml</file>
                </webwhales_variousmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My block class is located at `app/code/local/WebWhales/VariousModule/Block/Catalog/Categoryseo.php` and has the following content:

```
<?php
    class WebWhales_VariousModule_Block_Catalog_Categoryseo extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setTemplate( 'webwhales/seoblock.phtml' );
        }
    }
```

Right now I have no clue what the problem is or how to solve it. When I change `<reference name="category.products">` to `<reference name="content">` it works, but my code isn't loaded at the right place; it has to be loaded at the top of `category.products`.

I have also tried to change `<default>` to `<catalog_category_default>` or `<catalog_category_layered>`, but that doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: May be you have place seoblock.xml at wrong location.

If Checking this,you can put this file at app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/webwhales/seoblock.xml  from app/design/frontend/default/hookahs/layout/webwhales/seoblock.xml

Comment: What's the content of you catalog/category/view.phtml template ?

Comment: @AmitBera my layout file still get loaded because i tried to remove 'left' and 'right' blocks and it got removed. @DigitalPianism i have `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('webwhales_seoblock');?>` added in that file, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*category.products template file is view.phtml* `( app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/template/catalog/category)`.

Here the *child block does not automatically render*.You ***need to call the child block by***

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('webwhales_seoblock');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have tried it but it doens't work.

Comment: Chnage  handler tp catalog_category_view

Comment: what do you mean by handler?

Comment: just change  '<default>' to '< catalog_category_view>'

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed the handler to 'catalog_category_layered' and it worked